# Set up code to run every 24 hours

Tags: c#

For a side project at work I'm trying to have a piece of code that is run every 24 hours at a certain time. My boss asked me to use an infinite loop instead of C#'s timer class so that's the main constraint I'm working with. My problem is that the code will work for the first 24 hours (i.e. it will run the code on the day that I set it to) but then it won't update after that. I'm not being thrown any exceptions or errors so I'm assuming it's just a problem with my logic.

Here's the gist of the code I have now.

```
int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    DateTime currentdate = DateTime.Now;
    String time = currentdate.ToString("HH:mm");

    if ((time == "23:50" || time == "23:51") && i == 0)
    {
        HistoricalAverageCollection HAC = new HistoricalAverageCollection();
        HAC.ExecHAC();

        HistoricalAverageError HAE = new HistoricalAverageError();
        HAE.ExecHAE();
        FourWeekAverageCollection FWAC = new FourWeekAverageCollection();
        FWAC.ExecFWAC();
        FourWeekAverageError FWAE = new FourWeekAverageError();
        FWAE.ExecFWAE();

        DomainsReturningZeroTwentyFourHours DRZ = 
            new DomainsReturningZeroTwentyFourHours();
        DRZ.ExecDomainsReturningZero();

        context.SaveChanges();

        //Program should update every 24 horus
        i = 1;

        Console.Write("Updated The Historical Averages In The Data Base at...");
        Console.Write(DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine("i is -> {0}", i);
        Console.Read();
    }
    else if (time == "06:00" && i == 1)
    {
        ReportEmail Report = new ReportEmail();
        Report.CreateAndSendReport();
        i = 0;
        Console.Write("counter reset. I is now -> {0} /n Email Sent",i);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The code is set up to call a bunch of tsql stored procedures at 11:50 Pm and then send out an email report based on that data at 6 in the morning. However, it will only run once and I find myself waking up in the morning a day or two later and seeing that no emails are being sent.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Any reason you're not using scheduled tasks for this?

Comment: Is there a reason your boss didn't want to use the Windows Task Scheduler?  This is the exact thing it was made for.

Comment: Would it not be possible to use Windows task scheduler to run an exe every 24 hours? Windows task scheduler has a lot of customization options to get it to run every x amount of time and to repeat the process.

Comment: Why can't you try Task Scheduler. You can create a Scheduler and Make your application run every day at the time you want.

Comment: Lol! you know that you do not have to wait overnight? Just change times to values when you are awake and check what is wrong.

Comment: Why is everyone recommending scheduled tasks? This would work fine with a Thread.sleep for a specified time.

Comment: @Botonomous Because that's what scheduled tasks are for?  I want to run a thing every day.  I wonder if I can schedule that?  And why should a programmer be involved if that schedule changes?

Comment: @Botonomous: Because this is *exactly* the kind of task that schedule tasks are designed for. You have a short program to do this task, it runs at the scheduled time and then quits. Next day it runs again at the same time. Versus having a program that has to be running 24 hours a day, using resources and doing nothing most of the time.

Comment: Even if for some reason you won't use scheduled tasks and won't use one of the timer classes in .NET *at the very least* put a sleep in that loop so it's not constantly trashing the processor for no good reason.

Comment: And you appear to be using `i`, an `int` as a `bool`. Just use a `bool` already.

Answer (score 9):

I would second the many comments suggesting other, better suited methods of doing this, but I believe your problem is the lines with:

```
Console.Read();
```

From the documentation:

> The Read method blocks its return while you type input characters; it
>   terminates when you press the Enter key.

So it will block waiting for an entry that will never come.

Comment: I would prefer to use Windows Task Scheduler too, but for whatever reason that isn't ideal. The program doesn't really use a lot of resources so I decided it wasn't a big deal.

Comment: Ok, but since you only check for minutes, you can put a `Thread.Sleep(60000);` into your code, so it won't run needlessly. This stops the threads execution for a minute (60 (seconds) * 1000 (ms)).

Comment: Yeah I added that; appreciate the help. Still pretty novice at c#.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a time variable that indicates the "Next" datetime to run.

In your loop just check if the current time of after that and run your code.. then reset the variable to the next daytime i.e. Now + 24 hours.

as another answer indicates the issue is with the line:

```
Console.Read();
```

**which needs to be removed**

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this all by hand without using timers or existing scheduler facilities, I'd recommend being a little more rigorous and building a simple task scheduler class yourself. The parts you'll need:

- A class to store each task, which includes the code to execute for the task and the schedule for when each task should run.
- A list of such tasks
- A method to compute when the next deadline is from your list of tasks, so you know how long to sleep for.
- A SemaphoreSlim to sleep on (instead of `Thread.Sleep()`)

  - Use a SemaphoreSlim because it acts as a `Thread.Sleep()` by passing it a wait time if the semaphore is never released; but also because you can manually release it if your scheduler determines that a new task has been added and it should wake up to re-evaluate the next deadline.

I'd recommend storing your deadlines in UTC, and doing the majority of the time computation work using UTC time, this way there's no confusion about time zone changes or DST.

You also should consider not just sleeping for the entire time until the next deadline, just in case there are NTP updates to the PC's system time. Consider sleeping for a maximum of 1 hour at a time.

Some highlights to get you started:

```
public void Run()
{
    this.running = true;

    do
    {
        DateTime nextDeadlineUtc;
        ScheduledTask nextTask;
        bool deadlineExpired;

        nextDeadlineUtc = ComputeNextDeadline( out nextTask );

        deadlineExpired = WaitForDeadline( nextDeadlineUtc );

        if( deadlineExpired )
        {
            // We hit the deadline. Execute the task and move on.
            nextTask.Execute();
        }
        else
        {
            // We were woken up before the deadline expired. That means either we're shutting
            // down, or we need to recompute our next deadline because the schedule changed.
            // To deal with this, just do nothing. We'll loop back around and either find out
            // we're being asked to stop, or we'll recompute the next deadline.
        }
    }
    while( this.running );
}

/// <summary>
/// Sleeps until the deadline has expired.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="nextDeadlineUtc">The next deadline, in UTC</param>
/// <returns>
/// True if the deadline has elapsed; false if the scheduler should re-examine its next deadline.
/// </returns>
private bool WaitForDeadline( DateTime nextDeadlineUtc )
{
    TimeSpan wait;
    bool incompleteDeadline;
    bool acquired;

    wait = ComputeSleepTime( nextDeadlineUtc, out incompleteDeadline );

    acquired = this.waiter.Wait( wait );

    if( acquired || incompleteDeadline )
    {
        // Either:
        // - We were manually woken up early by someone releasing the semaphore.
        // - The timeout expired, but that's because we didn't wait for the complete time.
        // 
        // Either way, the deadline didn't expire.
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // The deadline occurred. 
        return true;
    }
}

private TimeSpan ComputeSleepTime( DateTime nextDeadlineUtc, out bool incompleteDeadline )
{
    TimeSpan totalRemaining = nextDeadlineUtc - DateTime.UtcNow;

    if( totalRemaining.Ticks < 0 )
    {
        // Were already out of time.
        incompleteDeadline = false;
        return TimeSpan.FromTicks( 0 );
    }
    else if( totalRemaining.TotalHours <= 1.01 )
    {
        // Just sleep the whole of the remainder.
        incompleteDeadline = false;
        return totalRemaining;
    }
    else
    {
        // More than one hour to sleep. Sleep for at most one hour, but tell the sleeper that
        // there's still more time left.
        incompleteDeadline = true;
        return TimeSpan.FromHours( 1.0 );
    }
}
```